# Issue at xinetd while installing check mk agent at Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I try to install the check mk agent at Ubuntu 14.04.The installation of the agent is successful but when I try to add this agent in web console the service is not shown at the web console of the server.so I have checked the status of `xinetd` where the service is already restart and checked but it shows only the unknown `job:xinetd`.

Why? Anyone knows why this is coming.When the `xinetd` is used in the other system installed with this agent is running the services without any issues.How to check the status of the `xinetd` and I needs to show the details of the check mk agent installed in the system.So please provide me the status how to do?